# Loop on mouseover

Tags: javascript, image, onmouseover

I have four images. When I mouseover them, I want each one of them to play a different sound. Well, I did that, but created different variables for each and also different functions. And in the HTML I have the container with the images and then in another `<div>` the audio. 
I create a new variable that selects all images and loops over them:

```
var roll = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i=0; i<roll.length; i++){
    roll[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
       console.log(this);
       this.audio.play();
    })
}
```

But then even that the "this" is the image it says: `Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`. And I getting confusing of how I connect the sound with the image.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="down music"><img id="batman" src="#"></div>   
   <div class="up music"><img id="bane" src="#"></div>
   <div class="down music"><img id="batman" src="#"></div>
   <div class="up music"><img id="batman" src="#"></div>
</div>

<audio id="batman" src="sounds/batman.wav"></audio>
<audio id="bane" src="sounds/ceremony.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="joker" src="sounds/free.wav"></audio>
<audio id="alfred" src="sounds/mud.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: what do you mean from `this.audio`? `this` is pointing to an image.

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour what i meant was that i was testing if i was selecting the correct image like i wanted. But with the audio, taking the this and changing the id, it plays but only one sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `this` is referring to each `<img>` tag, and not the audio sources. Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/alecdesjardins/pen/RJGaxQ) that `onMouseOver` alerts the corresponding div's value. (I did not have access to audio sources but should be relatively easy to switch over). The following should work for audio tags, granted I did not test this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="down music"><img id="monkey" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/145947/pexels-photo-145947.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" height="90"></div>   
   <div class="up music"><img id="dog" src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782" height="90"></div>
   <div class="down music"><img id="cat" src="https://www.bluecross.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail_pet/public/pets/149194.jpg?itok=xZLl3maM" height="90"></div>
   <div class="up music"><img id="cow" src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/puppy-dog.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782" height="90"></div>
</div>

<audio id="audiomonkey" src="#">monkey</audio>
<audio id="audiodog" src="#">dog</audio>
<audio id="audiocat" src="#">cat</audio>
<audio id="audiocow" src="#">cow</audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
var roll = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i=0; i<roll.length; i++){
    roll[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
       var idOfImg = this.id; //gets each id of the img
       document.getElementById("audio" + idOfImg).play(); //gets your right sound, based off id
    });
}
```

We get each id of the image by `this.id` and then get the corresponding element with **audio** in front of ID, and then just use the `.play()` method.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what you can do: embed each `audio` tag inside the `div` tags next to the `img` tags. This way you will have far less trouble finding the corresponding `audio` element when you've triggered one of the `img` elements.

Here is the new structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="down music">
    <img id="batman" src="#">
    <audio id="batman" src="sounds/batman.wav"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="up music">
    <img id="bane" src="#">
    <audio id="bane" src="sounds/ceremony.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="down music">
    <img id="joker" src="#">
    <audio id="joker" src="sounds/free.wav"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="up music">
    <img id="alfred" src="#">
    <audio id="alfred" src="sounds/mud.wav"></audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

Careful with the ids, but here it's irrelevant as we aren't going to use them.

Next, with JavaScript, we will:

1. select all the music `div`s:

   ```
   const roll = [...document.querySelectorAll('.music')];
   ```

   I'm using the destructuring syntax to convert the `NodeList` of `HTMLElement`s into an object `Array` of `HTMLElement`s.
2. Loop through all the elements of this array, i.e. all play `div`s. Instead of using a `for` loop I am using the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method directly on the array. It's a lot nicer. The method creates a new array with the results of calling the provided callback function on every element in `roll`.

   ```
   roll.map(function callback())
   ```

   The argument passed to the callback is the element of `roll` (here called `e`)
3. In the callback function, we use `querySelector` on `e` in order to find the child `img` element. We then attach the event listener to it:

   ```
   e.querySelector('img').addEventListener('mouseover', function insideCallback());
   ```
4. `addEventListener` also needs a callback function. It will simply select the child `audio` element and call the method `play()` on it:

   ```
   e.querySelector('img').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {

       e.querySelector('audio').play()

   });
   ```

---

So the final code is:

```js
const roll = [...document.querySelectorAll('.music')];

roll.map(e => {
  e.querySelector('img').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {

    e.querySelector('audio').play()

  });

});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="down music">
    <img id="batman" src="#">
    <audio id="batman" src="sounds/batman.wav"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="up music">
    <img id="bane" src="#">
    <audio id="bane" src="sounds/ceremony.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="down music">
    <img id="joker" src="#">
    <audio id="joker" src="sounds/free.wav"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="up music">
    <img id="alfred" src="#">
    <audio id="alfred" src="sounds/mud.wav"></audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code in js:

```
 window.onload = function () {
      var roll = document.querySelectorAll("img");
      roll.forEach(function (img, i) {
            img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                console.log(img);
                var indx = img.id.split('_').pop();
                playMusic(indx);
            });
        });
      }
 }
 function playMusic(indx) {
     var arr = ['sound_0', 'sound_1', 'sound_2', 'sound_3'];
     var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
     audio.src = 'sounds/' + arr[indx] + '.wav';
     audio.play();
 }
```

and html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="up music"><img id="img_0" src="#"></div>
    <div class="up music"><img id="img_1" src="#"></div>
    <div class="down music"><img id="img_2" src="#"></div>
    <div class="up music"><img id="img_3" src="#"></div>
 </div>
 <audio src="sounds/mud.wav"></audio>
```

Answer (score -1):

there are few issues with your code:

1. ids are repeating - id of HTML elements must be **unique** - this means that you can only have one element for a given id, instead use classes.
2. how do you imagine `this.audio.play()` would work while you iterate over plain HTML items?

you need to:

1. remove the ambiguous ids - replace them with classes
2. implement a way of reading those custom properties and playing given song

Comment: Yes you were right with the ids. It was not like that before, I had different ids for each one. Before my function was                           
  var image1 = document.getElementById("sound1");
var audio1 = document.getElementById("bane");

image1.onmouseover = function(){
    audio1.play()
    
}                                                                                                                  that for each function. So giving it a getElementsbyClass. Can i put a class for each sound and then iterate each for each image?